# Override LinearLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

The item_description is still at the bottom of the arrangement rather than located at the right of item_title.

Any suggestions?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical”>

    <ImageView
        … />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title”
        android:layout_width="150dp"

        …. />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_description”
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/item_title”
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/item_title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want that the item_description and item_title horizontal??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Constraints on a Linear Layout only on a ConstraintLayout.

Linear Layout items will always appear in the order you have specified them.

Change the Top level item to `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical”>

    <ImageView
        … />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal”>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title”
    android:layout_width="150dp"

    …. />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_description”
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/item_title”
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/item_title" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayout` arranges the views in a line, one after the other, either horizontally or vertically (which you've specified here). You could nest your two "horizontal" elements inside another, horizontal `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical”>

    <ImageView
        … />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal”>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title”
            android:layout_width="150dp"

            …. />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_description” />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or use a `ConstraintLayout`, which you're kinda trying to use by adding those constraints on the bottom `TextView` - but if you change the `LinearLayout` to `ConstraintLayout`, you'll need constraints on everything:

```
<ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent”
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent”
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent”
        … />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title”
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView”
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent”
        …. />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_description”
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/item_title”
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/item_title" />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

guessing a little about the layout you want here but you get the idea!